# Advice on Flood mapping of village area

Tags: mapping, flood

This is my first attempt to do a study on this topic.

I would like to get some advice on what data are required for doing flood mapping.

The area I have selected for this is a village which faces flooding every year.

I have got details about

1. Rainfall data
2. Soil type
3. Elevation of the area

And I have done some field surveying.

What other data are required?

Comment: Trees and vegetation perhaps? I am no expert, but I know that makes a difference.

Comment: Here's a dataset that's easily overlooked: ask the locals and the old timers. Their recollections can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to model flooding you will need various datasets:

- The river network!
- Flood defence structures such as embankments
- Structures that control/influence flow such as sluice gates, weirs
- Who is going to be affected, so buildings (type residential/business), infrastructure such as roads/rail/bridges
- What else is going to be affected? What about protected areas or species?
- Vegetation as suggested above
- High resolution elevation data such as LiDAR
- Derived datasets such as slope and floodplain.
- Geology
- Aerial photograph

Then there are other specialist datasets often derived from above which depend upon what you are working on. Are you looking at just impact or maybe you are modelling sediment movement? If for example you were looking a sediment then may be some erodability index is required?

Comment: dont forget the stormwater network as well.  how is the water getting out of the area?